# How to find out to which road each points belongs to?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, mxd, road, file-geodatabase

I am new to GIS . I hava a folder it include a .mxd file and a .gdb folder, the .gdb folder hava many .gdbtable and .gdbindexes  files etc, it's a road network data of a city. Now, I want to know which road it belongs to for a given latitude and longitude, which software or sdk should I use? is there have a similar open source project?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Spatial Join (Analysis)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000q000000) to join the information of the nearest road to your point (lat/long).

It will create another field in your point layer that belongs to the name of the nearest road.

See ya.

Answer (score 0):

[Near (Analysis)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001q000000) can be used to find the nearest line feature to each point feature. The tool will create a new field called 'NEAR_FID' in the point feature attribute table which holds the identifier of the nearest line.  A distance field is also created if this of use to you.

This tool is available in ArcGIS for Desktop with an ADVANCED license level only.